# NTFS Drobo External HDD not mounting properly

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Looked around for hours, but can't seem to find any advice better than "reformat it with ext3":

I have a Drobo 5D with 20+ TB of usable space, most of which is used with very important data. It has been working flawlessly on Windows, but we're trying to migrate our work over to Ubuntu for a variety of reasons, and the Drobo simply refuses to move with us. It's formatted with NTFS, and I'm trying to mount it on a new Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Using drobo-utils, I can verify that the system is plugged in and looks ready to go, but when I try to mount it, the command just hangs:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o force,rw /dev/sdc2 /data/drobo
```

When I check the command later:

```
ps aux | grep mount
root     19309  0.0  0.0  72716  4280 pts/3    S    17:36   0:00 sudo mount -t ntfs -o force,rw /dev/sdc2 /data/drobo
root     19310  0.0  0.0  32448  1332 pts/3    S    17:36   0:00 mount -t ntfs -o force,rw /dev/sdc2 /data/drobo
root     19311  0.0  0.0  21428  2884 pts/3    D    17:36   0:00 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdc2 /data/drobo -o rw,force
```

Notice that the CPU time is at 0:00, so it doesn't seem to be doing anything (this is an hour after issuing the command). I've pulled the drobo back off of linux and checked it out on Windows, and everything seems fine. There's too much data on it to try reformatting it at this point. Is there anything particular about NTFS that would be causing this? Or is it an issue with the Drobo in general when using NTFS? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run a `CHKDSK /F /R /B` on Windows first?  If there is a weird problem on the NTFS drive, it doesn't mount properly.  Also please add how many partitions this 20TB device has and whether any of the other partitions does mount. (create an empty one if you still have unallocated space for testing purposes only...) Then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby It has a single partition using the entire space. It's also been set up for single drive failure and mirroring, which results in the 5 8TB drives collapsing into about 20 TB of usable space. I've scheduled the CHKDSK but haven't had the chance to see if this changes anything from Linux's perspective yet.

Comment: try with the following options (without `force`) `rw,inherit,permissions,streams_interface=windows,windows_names,compression,norecover,hide_dot_files,hide_hid_files,big_writes` if on 18.x and feed back.

Comment: are you sure you have `ntfs-3g` installed ? Should be default..

Comment: @Fabby Go ahead and put your advice in an answer and I'll award the bounty. I'll update when I have time to work on this further. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: +1  Please do not forget to accept as well.  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `fsck` can repair some of the damage done to NTFS, it is not as good as the built-in Windows `CHKDSK` so run that first on a Windows machine:

```
CHKDSK /F /R /B
```

As you're running 18.x, you have the latest `ntfs-3g` driver installed, so use all of the advanced options in the mount command:

```
rw,inherit,permissions,streams_interface=windows,windows_names,compression,norecover,hide_dot_files,hide_hid_files,big_writes
```

and definitely do not `force` anything.

Having said the above, once you have it running, I strongly advise you to:

- get another external NAS of the same size
- format it using a modern FS like `ext4` or `btrfs`
- mount that one Read-Write
- mount the NTFS one Read-Only
- copy the files over as and when you need them to become R/W

Finally when all files are copied:

- Reformat the old one and use it to make `rsync` or `borg` backups of all your data.